# twitter gem showing array of numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, twitter, rubygems, haml

I'm using the twitter gem for rails, it's all set up and working fine, but after the tweet I have `[8]` and when I've pulled two tweets I get `[6,6]`

this is the code:

```
= Twitter.user_timeline('username', :count => 2).collect do |tweet|
  %li.twitter
    =raw auto_link(tweet.text)
```

I've also used the twitter-text gem

```
include Twitter::Autolink
```

and have this in my initializer:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
 config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
 config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
 config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
 config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end
```

Comment: Please paste your configuration for Twitter. I want to see, how did you set it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the problem is with your collect. Did you tried with each instead of collect:

```
= Twitter.user_timeline('username', :count => 2).each do |tweet|
  %li.twitter
    = auto_link(tweet.text)
```

Hope it will help.Thanks

Comment: it shows the two tweets but adds a whole load of stuff after it.. looks like a session dump or something

Comment: can you paste the output of Twitter.user_timeline('username', :count => 2).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
= Twitter.user_timeline ...
```

use

```
- Twitter.user_timeline ...
```

(i.e. change `=` to `-`).

`=` evaluates the expression and adds the result to the output, so after printing out the `li` elements for each tweet in the timeline Haml will print out the array itself.

You should also use `each` rather than `collect`. This won’t actually effect the result you see, but avoids creating a new array that just gets thrown away.